# Удаление строк из DataGridView

Tags: c#, компоненты

Мне нужно удалить из DataGridView все строки, в которых в какой-либо ячейке присутствует определенное значение. Мод код почему-то у меня удаляет иногда только первую запись. Не могу понять причину.

```
for (int i = 0; i < DataGridViewEdges.RowCount; i++)
    if ((System.Convert.ToInt32(DataGridViewEdges.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value).ToString() == (k + 1).ToString()) || (System.Convert.ToInt32(DataGridViewEdges.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value).ToString() == (k + 1).ToString())) {
        DataGridViewEdges.Rows.RemoveAt(i);
        EdgeNumber--;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DataSource задан у грида или там только виртуальные данные? Вообще неправильно менять набор данных, когда по ним "бежишь". Надо или сделать так:

```
var rowsToRemove = new List <object> ();

for (int i = 0; i < DataGridViewEdges.RowCount; i++)
    if ((System.Convert.ToInt32(DataGridViewEdges.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value).ToString() == (k + 1).ToString()) || (System.Convert.ToInt32(DataGridViewEdges.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value).ToString() == (k + 1).ToString()))
    {
        rowsToRemove.Add(DataGridViewEdges.Rows[i]);
        EdgeNumber--;
    }

foreach(var row in rowsToDelete)
{
    DataGridViewEdges.Rows.Remove(row);
}
```

Если есть всё же DataSource, то лучше изменять данные в нём, не ориентируясь на DataGrid вообще.

Comment: Нет, DataSource не задан.